# Excel: using a worksheet as a function?

Tags: excel

I've got an excel worksheet that takes two inputs and generates an output.

I can currently open the worksheet, type the two into cells A1 and A2, and the result shows up in A3.

Is there a way I can make this into a function or subroutine, such that I can can use it in another worksheet to fill in a table of values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Data tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-two-variable-data-table-HP005199586.aspx) could work for you, but you can't refer to a cell from a different sheet. At least, that's the case for Excel 2003, you can try it out in 2007 or 2010 to see if it works.

---

Other that that:

Yes, you can make a subroutine.
You can't make a worksheet function though, as they are not allowed to change sheets.

On that worksheet, create a function that goes:

```
public function GetWhatever(byval p1 as variant, byval p2 as variant) as variant
  'Make sure you're in AutoCalculation mode, otherwise use me.calculate
  me.range("A1").value = p1
  me.range("A2").value = p2
  GetWhatever = me.range("A3").value
end function
```

You then can repeatedly call this function from another procedure, which is on the second worksheet, and copy the newly aquired result into the next available row on your worksheet:

```
for i = 1 to 10
  me.cells(i,3).value = SheetWithCalculations.GetWhatever(me.cells(i,1).value, me.cells(i,2).value)
next
```

Comment: What you write doesn't make any sense ....You write
"You can't make a worksheet function though, as they are not allowed to change sheets." and then you show a function in which you change the cell ????
" me.range("A1").value = p1"

Comment: Care to explain why it doesn't make any sense @StéphaneGerber?

Comment: Can I contact you somewhere, I really need this to work, thank you.

Comment: @StéphaneGerber You are contacting me here (in an unhelpful way, so the discussion might be deleted by a mod for good). If you think this code does not do what it [should do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3570720/11683), please explain why in a comment.

Comment: Ok, got it ! You can only call function from VBA, not from the sheet. I didn't want to sound rude, it just Excel making me mad ...

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659779/set-a-cell-value-from-a-function helped me too ...